# New table row autopopulated with data from other rows?

Tags: database-design

I am in the middle of developing a simulated horse game using PHP and databases. Apparently I have just enough knowledge to get into trouble with my grand ideas! I'm looking for help/tips on my current task, creating new *horse stats* based on currently registered ones in a database.

I have a `horse` table containing data similar the following:

```
CREATE TABLE horse(id int, name text, stat1 int);
INSERT INTO horse VALUES
  (1,'sparky',20),
  (2,'spunky',10);
```

I want to create a new *horse* using the average of the *horse* 1 & 2's values contained in `stat1`. So *horse* 3 would have a `stat1` value of 15 that would be automatically calculated.

Is this possible using PHP? Or can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

If you want the average for all horses:

```
insert into horse (id, name, stat1)
select nextid, 'name', avg(stat1)
from horse;
```

If you want the average for a subset of horses you can add a where clause:

```
insert into horse (id, name, stat1)
select nextid, 'name', avg(stat1)
from horse
where ... ;
```

If id is autogenerated:

```
insert into horse (name, stat1)
select 'name', avg(stat1)
from horse
where ... ;
```